# After upgrade to 22.04 from 20.04 can not boot into Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, upgrade, bootloader

Actually, I was having a very similar problem before I upgraded, so 99.9% sure it is not that 22.04 is not fully bug-free [what Ubuntu ever is!?]. Before, the problem was that I had cloned the drive and then changed the UUIDs of the partitions. I had finally set it to look for the new UUID.

So, when booting in a stable manner again, I upgraded to 22.04. Since, I have not been able to boot into Ubuntu on the disk. I can into windoze 10 on the same disk. I have refind [can't now 'find' ubuntu - or at least can not boot it], I also have AIO...ditto.

Running various possibilities on those two above mentioned, if it does anything at all [usually not], it eventually drops to an intramsfs prompt - which I'm fairly clueless about.

I think the fix is not complicated, but I don't know how to get there. I have tried various things for several days, with no change other than growing frustration, as I use Windoz only 0.5% of the time. Most 'how to' posts semi-related either do not seem to fit my situation or I'm too linux-naive to make them work.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Usually I would post what I see on screen, but I don't know of any way to copy them from the screen. Boot-repair could not fix the problem and only reported errors. I can not post what its report said, as the address it gives says no paste posted [?!?!]. In the report which I read, it also makes two suggestions I tried, but could not get to fix the problem.

Comment: *"I was having a very similar problem before I upgraded"* - release upgrades do not fix preexisting problems, but performing a release upgrade does make it harder to find and fix them.  At this point you've already spent several days, so I suggest a reinstall. It won't take nearly as much time as you've already spent. FYI: it's rare that new software is 100% bug free. No matter how much testing is done, the release audience is always bigger with more variables. For LTS releases, this is why an upgrade isn't even offered until the first point release which is still months out.

Comment: Also since you've "tried various things" -- it's possible you need to undo some or more of these things. If you still want to try to fix this installation, please add all of the details of what you've tried so far.  For example, boot repair results can be sent to a pastebin. You can link that here. Knowing what you've already done is essential information to understand the state of your system. And unfortunately, the more things you try unsuccessfully, the more complicated the troubleshooting gets moving forward.

Comment: Are you able to boot to Recovery Mode from the GRUB menu?

Comment: All problems were fixed before upgrade. Almost sure the problem is wrong UUID is listed. I can not get into system to change it. Don't know how from grub or initramfs prompts. No reinstall - not going into why. Not days - weeks. How to proceed from grub or initramfs - as these seem to be the only places I can get to. Can not get into recovery mode. I see it is looking for the old UUID, but don't know how to change to new one.

Comment: Again, I am sure I only need to tell the system to look for the correct [changed] UUID. I see it searching "job running for" the wrong UUID...then it gives me a command prompt....but then what?

Comment: Not sure if it helps or not, but I guess initramfs configuration changed in 22.04. Hence while booting up system does not have a configured module for partprobe and cannot recognize all partitions. So I guess adding boot script to initramfs-tools will solve the problem.

Comment: "adding boot script to initramfs-tools" - I would not have the faintest idea how to do so. I put it into a search engine and it didn't really give any intelligible response. Using Super-grub2 and/or refind I can now boot into Ubuntu, but I certainly can NOT 'normally' - nor can I access Windows on the same drive anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished fighting a similar problem. 20.04 booted fine using UUIDs in the fstab however, after the upgrade to 22.04, I had to revert to /dev/sd* names. Everything was fine after that. When the boot fails and gives you the enter root password prompt, enter the password and look at fstab. If there's /dev/sd* entries commented out, comment out the UUID lines and enable the other ones. Save the file and reboot See if it works after that. YMMV.